# What package, software or particular tool produced this bar plot?

Tags: visualization, plotting

Would anyone be able to identify the package or tool used to created this particular bar plot? It has a distinctive font.

[image]
Source (with paywall): https://towardsdatascience.com/stopping-covid-19-with-misleading-graphs-6812a61a57c9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bar chart made using Google sheets, see also this chart which was made with Google sheets:

[image]

Comment: Nice! I've never used google sheet. need to learn... maybe somewhere there is an option for put the numbers as a label.

Answer (score 1):

It's really difficult to know with what tool they do that. but I will give my chances to R or Excel. That overlapping is automatic perform with excel just selecting the data this is the instruction-: Go to the insert section: char category and choose the 2-D Column, Style 7, Layout 16.

[image]

also you can perform a "similar" plot with ggplot and the theme pubclean.
( maybe you need to check the themes of ggpubr )

```
# Create the bar plot. Use theme_pubclean() [in ggpubr]
ggplot(df, aes(x = cut, y = counts)) +
  geom_bar(fill = "#0073C2FF", stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = counts), vjust = -0.3) + 
  theme_pubclean()
```

[image]

Just for check again and give to you reasons about this graph. That webpage continue with another bar chart with the dates stacked in vertical position.

[image]

Using Excel with some old visualization( check the dates ):

[image]

Note: If my data is small the dates will look like the above chart.

References:

R graphics essentials: Plot One Variable, Frequency Graph, Density Distribution and More:

http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/32-r-graphics-essentials/133-plot-one-variable-frequency-graph-density-distribution-and-more/